# Copy nested JSON to Azure sql with Azure Data Factory

Tags: json, stored-procedures, azure-sql-database, azure-data-factory

I have a nested JSON stored in a Data Lake on Azure , it has this format:

```
    {"proto": "01",
     "type": "A",

 "description": "heartbeat",
 "geometry": {"y0_1": {"tag": "Normal",
   "probability": 0.40,
   "x": 39,
   "y": 13},
  "y0_2": {"tag": "category_3", "probability": 0.8, "x": 48, "y": 13},
  "y0_3": {"tag": "Normal", "probability": 0.9, "x": 27, "y": 10},
"Test": {"proba": 0.65}}}
```

I want to create ADF Pipeline (with triggers) to move it from Data Lake to Azure Sql.
The problem is when I create a copy Activity, the mapping isn't recognized by ADF ,
It creates a table with 4 columns: proto, type, description, but the 4th one geometry contains all the rest of the json file in one row.
While I want to have an output table in this format:

```
proto    type    description    tag       probability    x    y     proba
01        A      heartbeat      Normal     0.40          39   13     0.65
01        A      heartbeat      category_3 0.8           48   13     0.65
01        A      heartbeat      Normal     0.9           27   10     0.65
```

I tried to parse the json directly on SQL using CROSS APPLY tool, but I have trouble making the JSON to copy from ADLS to SQL directly with the wanted mapping on ADF
If anyone has some guidance or any idea that I can follow, it will be much appreciated

Comment: Per my experience, Data Factory doesn't work well with the nested json.

Comment: Hi @Zin, If the answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer. This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Per my experience, Data Factory doesn't work well with the nested json.

To get your expect output, you may need create three copy actives to achieve that. Each active with the same source and sink. And create the table firstly in sink database.

Pipeline overview:
[image]

The differences are the mapping setting in each copy active.

Copy active1: copy data `geometry.y0_1` to sink:
[image]

Copy active2: copy data `geometry.y0_2` to sink:
[image]

Copy active3: copy data `geometry.y0_3` to sink:
[image]

Output data in sink table:
[image]

Some other ways, you could create a stored procedure in database to deal with the JSON data, choose the stored procedure in sink like bellow:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Leon Yue for your answer , the only issue is that I have a very long json, and I can't create manually many copy activities.

Comment: Hi @Zin, as I said, data factory doesn't work well with nested json. It' s very hard or can't achieve your request. We can't mapping it to the sink table because the `geometry` can not consider as the collection.